# phpmyadmin: why is my field with type "text" unique and primary?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created table with 4 fields. the very first column is "id", which is auto increment and is primary and unique. the second one is type="text". But for some reason it defaults to be unique and primary. Why is that? And how do I set up that field to be just a regular field?

Comment: since i have never seem PMA do this, i can only assume you ticked the boxes to make it so.

Comment: he dident use code, he used PMA - so um

Comment: Yes, I used PMA and that's what I thought so I dropped the field.. and added another one and made sure no unique is chosen... but it keeps adding that column as unique and primary

Comment: of the thousands of Field's added that way i have never seen that happen - so um

Comment: I know it's weird.. I keep trying to add any other fields with type "text", but it's making them unique and primary!

Comment: If at all possible can u share the screenshot that  causes the problem.